# Buffer overflow - set relevant text to be printed

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, shellcode

```
#include <unistd.h>

char shellcode[] = "???";

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int* ret;
    ret = (int*) &ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (int) shellcode;
}
```

I have to change `shellCode` variable to have this year printed after launching this program.
I understand this code in the way that `ret` points at its previous address + 2, and it has value of the address where `shellCode` array begins.
But how the stack looks like in this case? I just don't understand the sense of the code in `main()` and how buffer-overflow works here.

EDIT
Ok, my question isn't as obvious as I thought. I can ONLY change what is inside `shellcode`, I can't add anything to this code (except changing `shellcode`) and the output should be `2019` (treat it like outputting every other number, ie. `2000`, the number will be hardcoded)

Comment: One thing to point out is that `ret` points to its own address plus 2 (rather than being based on what it was previously pointing to).

Comment: I do not understand what your objective is for the three lines of code in `main()`, but getting a string version of the current year, then printing it to `stdout` is pretty straight forward, and can be done by using the  _[strftime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)_ function.

Answer (score 0):

*I have to change shellCode variable to have this year printed after launching this program.*

Using *[strftime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)*, the following code can be used to populate `shellcode` with the current year,   (If `shellcode` is created with enough space.):

```
char shellcode[] = "0000"; //increase space for 4 characters + nul.

...  

time_t t;
struct tm* tm_info;
time(&t);
tm_info = localtime(&t);
strftime(shellcode, 5, "%Y", tm_info); //populate shellcode with year.
printf("%s\n", shellcode);             //write current year to stdout
```

As I mentioned in the comments, I am not sure what you are doing in the main function, but if your intent was to get an integer version of the current year, you can daisy chain the string results of *strftime* with the *[strtol](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)* function to convert the string to a numeric:

```
char *temp = null;
long int year = strtol(shellcode, &temp, 0);
```

But be sure to check for conversion errors.  eg:

```
if(temp == shellcode|| ((year == LONG_MIN || year == LONG_MAX) && errno == ERANGE))
{
    //handle error
}
```